# How can I filter results "live" with Vue?

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js

I have an input v-model and I want to filter through a product list.

Here is my filter. The problem is that it only works if the item name matches the input exactly. How can I modify the filter to see any partial matches as the input is being typed?

```
Vue.filter('byName', function (data, input) {

if(input){
    return data.filter(function (item) {
        return item.name == input
    });
}

return data

});
```

Comment: Unclear what you're asking. Explain "only matching products live"...

Comment: You are probably looking for the `String.prototype.indexOf()` or `String.prototype.includes()` method.

Comment: If you thought my solution was useful, upvote it :D. It's good etiquette to give [unicorn dollars](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194061/is-it-acceptable-to-ask-for-upvote-accept-in-an-answer-when-submitting-it#answer-194063) to answers that helped you out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to see "live" results, then you need to code your filter so that it returns items that partially match.

The simplest way is to use the `startsWith()` method. The following filter uses `startsWith()` to match all items that start with the input:

```
Vue.filter('byName', function (data, input) {
  if(input){
    return data.filter(function (item) {
      // we check if the item's name starts with the input
      return item.name.startsWith(input);
    });
  }
  return data
});
```

[Here is a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/asemahle/ay4h66t3/) of that filter in action.

On the other hand, if you wanted to return items that match **anywhere**, not just ones that started with the input, you can use `String.prototype.indexOf()`.

To do this, replace

```
// we check if the item's name starts with the input
return item.name.startsWith(input);
```

with

```
// we check if the item's name contains the input as a substring
return item.name.indexOf(input) > -1;
```